# Create new page in Joomla or add some text to existing page

Tags: menu

Please visit [this link](http://naadiastrology.info/): in footer you can see "online payment", If I click on "online payment", it should go to some page, means if I click on "online payment", it should open some page with some text.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not opening any page because it has a blank link. I'm not sure how you have set your footer up, put the links within it, should be pulled from the menu manager.

In your menu manager, there will most likely be a menu called "footer". Open it and you will see the desired menu item. Open that then you can set the type to whatever you wish.

If you set the type to something such as a Single Article, then be sure to actually define that article.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. I need help in linking menu to article. I read somewhere "Select Article - this option is within the right sliders titled 'Required Settings'", but where is this required settings?

Comment: It's literally right below where you set the type. The required setting should appear in red if they have not been selected. Look here >> http://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Single_Article

Comment: I am on " Menu Manager: Edit Menu Item " page.

but there is no "required settings" option in right side, i 

am seeing 2 options " Link type options"

and " module asignement for this menu item" i am seeing only these 2 options. its 2.5.8 version.

but i need "required settings" for assigning article to menu item.

Comment: It's very simple. There is an option to select the *type*. This brings up an modal box and you select *Single Article*. The modal box then closes. Then the next option is to select the article. Click is and this will also bring up a modal box. Save the menu item

Comment: hi, 

thanks a lot for your help.